# How to handle multiple selection for a UICollectionView, which changes data on swipe?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, multipleselection

I have a UICollectionView on a UIViewController, which changes data on swipe, it also has search. I change the array values and reload the UICollectionView every swipes. Now when I tried to implement multiple selection, selection changes on scrolling.

the code I use is,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchIsOn {
            return filteredTeamNames.count
        }
        else{
            return teamNames.count
        }        
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierTwo, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HouseCells

        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6            

        var singleComponent = [String : String]()
        if searchIsOn {
             singleComponent = self.filteredTeamNames[indexPath.item]
        } else {
             singleComponent = self.teamNames[indexPath.item]
        }
        let stringURL: String = singleComponent["icon_profile"]!

        cell.teamImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: stringURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "demo"))
        cell.teamNameLabel.text = singleComponent["username"]

        //to check for bg color
        let idValue: Int = Int(singleComponent["id"]!)!
        print(idValue)

        if selectedTeamIDs.contains(idValue) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:0/255, blue:0/255, alpha:1.0)
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:56/255, green:192/255, blue:201/255, alpha:1.0).cgColor

        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:26/255, blue:26/255, alpha:0.4)

        }

        return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var singleComponent = [String : String]()
        if searchIsOn {
            singleComponent = self.filteredTeamNames[indexPath.item]

        } else {
            singleComponent = self.teamNames[indexPath.item]

        }
        let idTempValue: Int = Int(singleComponent["id"]!)!
        print(idTempValue)

        if !selectedTeamIDs.contains(idTempValue) {
            selectedTeamIDs.append(idTempValue)

        }
        print(selectedTeamIDs)

        middleSectionCollView.reloadData()

    }
```

The array selectedTeamIDs contains unique numbers, so if the user clicks on particular index, I'd added the corresponding id to selectedTeamIDs array and in **cellForItemAt** ,I'm checking if the current index value's id exists in selectedTeamIDs array and if yes I'm changing the background color of the cell. But my code isn't working, selection changes on scrolling. Where am I missing the logic?

Comment: Have you set this  collectionView?.allowsMultipleSelection property to true? and what is this middleSectionCollView?why are you using it?

Comment: yes, I'd done that in ViewDidLoad, middleSectionCollView.allowsMultipleSelection = true. Still selection changes on scrolling!

Comment: try to remove this statement middleSectionCollView.reloadData() in didSelect method and then run your program

Comment: If I remove that line, how will the selection be updated in the view? cellForItemAt won't get called and no update will happen?

Comment: have you tried it? what is the result?

Comment: I tried, selected cells' background doesn't change

Comment: Try replacing middleSectionCollView.reloadData() with collectionView.reloadData and then run your program

Comment: There is another problem in your code that you posted, please add return cell at the end of cellForItemAt method

Comment: No change when I used, collectionView.reloadData. Infact when I select a cell some more cells are getting selected. About the return cell - I missed that line while pasting the code here.

Comment: Ok just remove this reload line and let me see if I can solve this problem,

Comment: Ok let me understand you problem, you want the cell to be selected and change its background color, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right the background color must change on selection.

Comment: Ok when you remove reload line and scroll then the cell remain selected or not?

Comment: Is your problem solved?If not, please check the answer and give your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First dont `reloadData` inside `didSelectItemAt` method, remove the reload line

Second in your custom cell class HouseCells (by the way name of a class should be a singular)

add this code

```
  override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {

            if isSelected {
                backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:0/255, blue:0/255, alpha:1.0)
                layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:56/255, green:192/255, blue:201/255, alpha:1.0).cgColor

            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:26/255, blue:26/255, alpha:0.4)

            }


        }
    }
```

Also remove this code from `cellForItemAt` method

```
if selectedTeamIDs.contains(idValue) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:0/255, blue:0/255, alpha:1.0)
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:56/255, green:192/255, blue:201/255, alpha:1.0).cgColor

        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:26/255, blue:26/255, alpha:0.4)

        }
```

And in your `didSelectItemAt` method you dont need this code now:

```
if !selectedTeamIDs.contains(idTempValue) {
            selectedTeamIDs.append(idTempValue)

        }
        print(selectedTeamIDs)

        middleSectionCollView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I found out the mistake, I understand that reloadData() line is useless, my code was working right, the bordercolor was messing while scrolling. I changed the else part like this and it works now,
if selectedTeamIDs.contains(idValue) {
              ...
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:26/255, blue:26/255, alpha:0.4)
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor}

Comment: @swiftDevStart good, please accept the answer if it helped you, please try this technique, this is far better than writing code inside tableview methods,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, since this is also a right answer, I'm accepting it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The given code is right, except for an issue with two lines of code in the else part as in,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchIsOn {
            return filteredTeamNames.count
        }
        else{
            return teamNames.count
        }        
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierTwo, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HouseCells

        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 6            

        var singleComponent = [String : String]()
        if searchIsOn {
             singleComponent = self.filteredTeamNames[indexPath.item]
        } else {
             singleComponent = self.teamNames[indexPath.item]
        }
        let stringURL: String = singleComponent["icon_profile"]!

        cell.teamImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: stringURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "demo"))
        cell.teamNameLabel.text = singleComponent["username"]

        //to check for bg color
        let idValue: Int = Int(singleComponent["id"]!)!
        print(idValue)

        if selectedTeamIDs.contains(idValue) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:0/255, blue:0/255, alpha:1.0)
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:56/255, green:192/255, blue:201/255, alpha:1.0).cgColor

        } else { cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:26/255, green:26/255, blue:26/255, alpha:0.4) 
                 cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                 cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
} 

        return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var singleComponent = [String : String]()
        if searchIsOn {
            singleComponent = self.filteredTeamNames[indexPath.item]

        } else {
            singleComponent = self.teamNames[indexPath.item]

        }
        let idTempValue: Int = Int(singleComponent["id"]!)!
        print(idTempValue)

        if !selectedTeamIDs.contains(idTempValue) {
            selectedTeamIDs.append(idTempValue)

        }
        print(selectedTeamIDs)

        middleSectionCollView.reloadData()

    }
```

Hope this answer will be usefull for someone!